# An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Tags: asp.net-mvc, smtpclient

**Description :**

I'm sending an email from MVC application, mail was sent successfuly when I send it to a single person but when I send mail to multiple people then getting an exception i.e. **Operation has timed out.**

So, to avoid this problem I'm trying use smtpclient.SendAsync(message,object) method but I'm getting an exception i.e. **An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.**

**How to resolve this problem ?**

**Code:**

```
 public async Task<string> SendEmail(List<string> ToEmailAddresses,string body, string emailSubject)
        {


            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Host = "xyz-host-name",
                Port = 25,
                EnableSsl = false,
                Timeout = 600000
            };

            var fromAddress = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailUserName"], "Rewards and Recognition Team");

            using (var message = new MailMessage() { Subject = emailSubject, Body = body })
            {
                message.From = fromAddress;

                foreach (string email in ToEmailAddresses)
                {
                    message.To.Add(email);
                }
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                try
                {
                    _logger.Log("EmailService-SendEmail-try");
                    object userToken = message;
                     smtp.SendAsync(message,userToken);
                    return "Success";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.Log("EmailService-SendEmail-" + ex.Message);
                    return "Error";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the await keyword in actionresult (controller side)

like

```
 public async task<ActionResult> SendMail(object obj)

{
var result = await SendEmail(ToEmailAddresses,body,emailSubject)
return result
}
```